# Geocoder.configure returns no method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geocoder

I am trying to configure geocoder with geocoder 0.9.11 in rails 7.  Every time I call Geocoder.configure in initializers/Geocoder.rb and in console it returns a no method error.  I originally have a timeout error using the free lookup like yandex, but I cannot manage to get at Geocoder.configure which I assume is now different in newer geocoder versions?  If this is in fact the problem that the free service is just too slow, are there premium services I can use?

Geocoder configure and timeout errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why on earth would you be using such an old gem? Unsurprisingly, the `Geocoder.configure` API was not present back in 2011, hence why you're getting the `NoMethodError`.

Comment: Thank you I must have just made a blunder thinking to got the right gem, doh! Thanks for your answer, I will level up to the next gem with configure didn't realize it was not in the earlier version thanks, just some info in the api gotta sharpen up my technical references :)

Comment: Heh, happens to us all. Btw, small #protip: if you look at the tags in a gem you'll usually find version tags, which you can click on and see the README for that version which often has (enough) docs of the API to put you on the right path.

Comment: great answer thanks turns out i was working on this a and changed back to webpacker, i actually can't remember much but noticing it was reading the wrong files and errors indicated a javascript issue with css and I neglected to enter --webpacker and copied some files for the rails new -d=mysql css=bootstrap -webpacker without webpacker and copied some old files I believes just a bandwith issue prevented me from working on this continuously just in my spare time. thumbs up.